# Android tabs+swipe fragments redrawing

Tags: android, fragment, gestures, redraw

I'm using android feature for Tabs+Swipe application. It generated most of my code. I have MainActivity, SectionsPagerAdapter and Fragment classes. In this application I will have 2 tabs, so I created 2 different fragment classes for each tab. but on first tab I need a fragment with spinner in it and some table with values underneath the spinner. What I need is that on spinner item selection I want to redraw same type of fragment with only different values in table.

Also I cannot use layout xml files for fragment cause the table does not have always same number of columns or rows. I need to programmatically design it's view. I cannot use nested fragments either cause I need my application to be destined for lower version of Android... and nested fragments are for newest 4.2 ver.

I have written some code based on similar questions I found here, but I still have the problem. Here is my fragment class with emphasis on spinner selection listener.

```
     public class CurrencyListFragment extends Fragment {
    ...

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    ...

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
    ...
                selection = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        Fragment fragment = new CurrencyListFragment(selection);
                        fragment.setArguments(result);
                        trans.replace(container.getId(), fragment);
                        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        trans.addToBackStack(null);
                        trans.commit();
                    }

                }
    }
```

I skipped some parts of the code.

I don't get why this is not working ... I don't get any error but instead of redrawing same fragment on first tab with different table values I get blank fragment.... nothing on it.

Is there a possible solution for this?

Comment: @TechExchange Be careful when retagging; you misspelled "gestures". I fixed it for ya :)